# Symfony2: Redirecting to last route and flash a message?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having a small problem when trying to flash a message and redirect the user back to the previous page in **Symfony 2**.

I have a very simple CRUD. When new, or edit, i want to flash a message if something goes wrong in the respective create/update methods:

1. `User --GET--> new`
2. `new --POST--> create (fails)`
3. `--REDIRECT--> new (with flash message)`

I'm doing the following:

```
  $this->container->get('session')->setFlash('error', 'myerror');
  $referer = $this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');   
  return new RedirectResponse($referer);
```

However, it's not redirecting to the correct referrer! Even though the value of referrer is correct (eg.: `http://localhost/demo/2/edit/`) It redirects to the index. Why?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is an alternative version of Naitsirch and Santi their code. I realized a trait would be perfect for this functionality. Also optimized the code somewhat. I preferred to give back all the parameters including the slugs, because you might need those when generating the route.

This code runs on PHP 5.4.0 and up. You can use the trait for multiple controllers of course. If you put the trait in a seperate file make sure you name it the same as the trait, following PSR-0.

```
<?php
trait Referer {
    private function getRefererParams() {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        $baseUrl = $request->getBaseUrl();
        $lastPath = substr($referer, strpos($referer, $baseUrl) + strlen($baseUrl));
        return $this->get('router')->getMatcher()->match($lastPath);
    }
}

class MyController extends Controller {
    use Referer;

    public function MyAction() {
        $params = $this->getRefererParams();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
            $params['_route'],
            [
                'slug' => $params['slug']
            ]
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, I replaced `$request->getBaseUrl()` by `$this->get('request')->getSchemeAndHttpHost()` because, "getBaseUrl()" returns an empty string. I'm using symfony 2.5

Comment: Not even 2.5 but 2.3 got the same problem too.

Comment: Not that cool as this trait will only work in Controller. Better way is to create service which has `request.stack` dependency. You can then get master request from it and return referrer in any context.

Comment: $request->headers->get('referer') does not return the correct $_SERVER[''HTTP_REFERER''] for me

Comment: @codemagician $_SERVER is directly passed into the ServerBag class. `"HTTP_"` is then stripped from the key https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/32ec28857a4b30e8c67202bec294ab57c083181a/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ServerBag.php#L33-L35 the resulting array is passed into HeaderBag. The HeaderBag uses `set` to construct it's values, and you use `get` to get the value. Both force headers to lowercase https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/32ec28857a4b30e8c67202bec294ab57c083181a/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/HeaderBag.php#L112-L153 Double check if the error is not on your end.

Comment: For symfony2.4+ you should use

`$request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();`

Answer (score 23):

For symfony 3.0,flash message with redirection back to previous page,this can be done in controller.

```
           $request->getSession()
                ->getFlashBag()
                ->add('notice', 'success');
            $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
            return $this->redirect($referer);
```

Answer (score 12):

The message from Naitsirch presented in the next url:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2951

Seems a good solution for that you need:

```php
public function getRefererRoute()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    //look for the referer route
    $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
    $lastPath = substr($referer, strpos($referer, $request->getBaseUrl()));
    $lastPath = str_replace($request->getBaseUrl(), '', $lastPath);

    $matcher = $this->get('router')->getMatcher();
    $parameters = $matcher->match($lastPath);
    $route = $parameters['_route'];

    return $route;
}
```

Then with a redirect:

```php
public function yourFunctionAction()
{
    $ruta = $this->getRefererRoute();

    $locale = $request->get('_locale');
    $url = $this->get('router')->generate($ruta, array('_locale' => $locale));

    $this->getRequest()->getSession()->setFlash('notice', "your_message");   

    return $this->redirect($url);
}
```

Comment: be careful with urls with additional GET parameters.
f.e. url: /test will match the route but /test?extra will not
(ofc it depends on definition of your routes)

Comment: This gave me an error: `Warning: strpos(): Empty needle` and I realized my referring route was the index page `/`.

Comment: This is not working in my app (SF 2.5.9) `$request->getBaseUrl()` seems always empty

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```
$this->redirect($request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER'));
```

Comment: HTTP_REFERER can be altered by the web server, proxy or web browser.

Comment: Have the same with `$this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));`

Comment: This opens a breach to open redirect attacks. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 4):

I have similar functionality on my site. It is multilingual. Articles exists only in a single locale. When the user will try to switch to other locale, it should redirect back to previous page and flash message that that page/article doesn't exist on the requested locale.

```
/en/article/3 -> /fr/article/3 (404) -> Redirect(/en/article/3)
```

Here is my version of the script that works well on `dev` and `prod` environments:

```php
$referer = $request->headers->get('referer')

// 'https://your-domain.com' or 'https://your-domain.com/app_dev.php'
$base = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . $request->getBaseUrl();

// '/en/article/3'
$path = preg_replace('/^'. preg_quote($base, '/') .'/', '', $referer);

if ($path === $referer) {
    // nothing was replaced. referer is an external site
} elseif ($path === $request->getPathInfo()) {
    // current page and referer are the same (prevent redirect loop)
} else {
    try {
        // if this will throw an exception then the route doesn't exist
        $this->container->get('router')->match(
            // '/en/hello?foo=bar' -> '/en/hello'
            preg_replace('/\?.*$/', '', $path)
        );

        // '/app_dev.php' . '/en/article/3'
        $redirectUrl = $request->getBaseUrl() . $path;

        return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
    } catch (\Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException $e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just set up a simple app, and it seems to work fine. My createAction() looks like this:

```
public function createAction()
{
    $entity  = new Pokemon();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new PokemonType(), $entity);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($entity->getName() == "pikachu")
    {
        $this->container->get("session")->setFlash("error", "Pikachu is not allowed");
        $url = $this->getRequest()->headers->get("referer");
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pokemon_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

    }

    return $this->render('BulbasaurBundle:Pokemon:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

The flow goes:

- User navigates to /new
- User enters invalid option of "pikachu"
- User clicks submit (POSTs to /create)
- Application rejects the entry, adds flash message, and redirects back to /new
- User sees /new with the flash message

A few things to check:

- Is your route for `/demo/{entityId}/edit` actually working? (i.e. if you enter it in the browser, does it actually go to where you expect it to?)
- Are you chaining together different redirects/forwards? I've noticed that I get unexpected (but correct) behavior when I have a controller that redirects to a URL, and the controller responsible for that URL also redirects somewhere else. I've fixed this issue by using forwards instead.

That said, if all else fails, you could just use the controller's redirect() method to manage the redirect:

```
public function createAction()
{
    ...
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("pokemon_new"));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, declare this as a service and it will return referer to you wherever and whenever you need it. No traits, no weird dependencies.

```
class Referer
{

    /** @var RequestStack */
    private $requestStack;

    /** @var RouterInterface */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->router       = $router;
    }

    public function getReferer() : string
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest();

        if (null === $request)
        {
            return '';
        }

        //if you're happy with URI (and most times you are), just return it
        $uri = (string)$request->headers->get('referer');

        //but if you want to return route, here you go
        try
        {
            $routeMatch = $this->router->match($uri);
        }
        catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e)
        {
            return '';
        }

        $route = $routeMatch['_route'];

        return $route;
    }

}
```

Comment: That might be better in some use cases. "Better" is very questionable though. Consider the the downsides: Dealing with the request object is the responsibility of the controller primarily. Class is heavier than a single trait. Service container get's larger. More configuration. Creation of service object even when you don't need it. Service needs DIC and thus creates dependencies.

Comment: I both agree and disagree. In pure MVC yes, controller would be best place. In Symfony what controller really does is just a really small part of `getresponse` event flow. There's also a reason that we have `request.stack` and DIC - why not use them to make reusable code with loose coupling? I would not mind about performance, as until you use route matching, whole logic is quite light. So I introduced request matching only as an option, marked by comment in code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need to have a payload for your redirect to point to. it seems like obscure concept code to me. I would also advise you to make sure your configuration files point to the correct redirect code snippet. Check your server access file to make sure it has redirects enabled also.