# router match url with parameters

Tags: symfony, routes

In my `Symfony2` project i have a `route` with parameters:

```
my_route:
    pattern:  /{param1}/{param2}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:MyController:myAction }
```

and in the action `myAction` i get the url and i when i try to get the corresponding route by matching the url i get this error:

```
 500 Internal Server Error - ResourceNotFoundException
```

and then the stack trace show this message :

```
1. in C:\Users\itaziny\git\Symfony\app\cache\dev\appDevUrlMatcher.php at line 459 

  throw 0 < count($allow) ? new MethodNotAllowedException(array_unique($allow)) : new ResourceNotFoundException();
```

this my code:

```
public function myActionAction(Request $request) {
   $url = $request->headers->get('referer');
   $router = $this->get('router');
   $route = $router->match($url);
   // Some code...

   if (route == "my_route") {
       // redirect to the pag: my_route
   }
   else {
      //redirect to the page who called this action
   }
}
```

the action: `myAction` is called from 2 different pages, and i have to redirect to the page who called the action `myAction`

Comment: Please visit the page using `app_dev.php`, to get a better error message

Comment: i'm using app_dev.php , i edited the question to show the stack trace

Comment: Please add the code of the called function from the Controller (it seems to be `myActionAction()`). What are you trying to do? Why do you want to know the corresponding route? How many routes call this function of the controller?

Comment: i edited the code of `myAction`

Comment: `$param1` and `$param2` are not passed to your Controller, try to add them as arguments: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#mapping-a-url-to-a-controller

Comment: i already have them as parameters of the action and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally find the answer here :
[Symfony2: Redirecting to last route and flash a message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892080/symfony2-redirecting-to-last-route-and-flash-a-message)

so what i did exactly is this:

```
$uri = $request->headers->get('referer');
$baseUrl = $request->getBaseUrl();
$lastPath = substr($uri, strpos($uri, $baseUrl) + strlen($baseUrl));

$route = $this->get('router')->match($lastPath);
if ($route['_route'] == "my_route") {
    // redirect to the pag: my_route
}
else {
  //redirect to the page who called this action
```

}