# Rendering a template without changing the route in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I've made a login function in which I render a template after checking the login and password. This's the form that i've made inside a template.

```
<form action="{{ path("login") }}" method="post" id="formulaire_connexion">
 <label class="control-label">Email
 <input  type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your@email.com" onclick="this.select()"/>
  </label>
   <label class="control-label">Password</br>
   <input  type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="*********" onclick="this.select()"/>
   </label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me"><label for="remember_me">Remember me </label></br>
   <button type="submit" id="connexion" name="connexion">Connexion</button>
   </form>
```

And this's the logging check method :

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $mail = $request->get('email');
    $pass = $request->get('password');
    $oauth = new OAuth($mail, $pass);

    $baseUrl = "http://api.localhost/v1/";
    $connexion = "{$baseUrl}login/".$mail."/".$pass;

    $oauth->fetch($connexion, $_REQUEST, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET);

    $reponseInformations = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse(), true);


    if (!$reponseInformations) {

        $data['erreur'] = "Bad credentials";

        return $this->render('EspacePointDeVenteBundle:Authentication:authentication.html.twig', array(
            'erreur' => $data,
        ));

    }else{
        return $this->render('EspacePointDeVenteBundle:Home:index.html.twig', array(
            'reseau' => $reseau,
            'identifiant' => $key,
            'key' => $identifiant,
        ));
    }

}
```

After a wrong login connexion I render the same login template, but the routing is changed to /login instead of havig /index per example. What I need to know how to keep the same routing even if we called a foreign method.

Comment: it´s because your form´s action is "/login" so if auth fails you could check the refferer and redirect back, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892080/symfony2-redirecting-to-last-route-and-flash-a-message

Comment: Side note: A good practice is to **never** render something on POST request, always redirect to a GET one.