# Symfony 4, how redirect the user after login (or logout) to the previous page?

Tags: symfony4

By example, the user go to the "about me" page. From this page, he can login or logout via a button in the navbar.

When the user login or logout, he is automatically redirected to the home page. Instead, I want redirect the user to the previous page (the "about me" in this example)

After read the doc I don't find/understand how I can condifure the redirection for my purposes

Someone can explain/show me :? thank you !

Comment: Look this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19471283/8338464

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide information about your implementation, so I will write with assumption, that you are using Symfony4 form authenticator. So basically you have a class which handles each stage of authentication for you (which you generated using ***make:auth*** from command line).

First, check out [THIS Symfony doc page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#generating-the-login-form), where they explain how to build basic authentication. At the bottom of this page they actually mention what I describe here in a bit more detail.

When you are **logged out** and click login (or try to go to a restricted page), before Symfony redirects to the login page, it saves the current URL into the session. You need to access this value in your **onAuthenticationSuccess()** method.

To do this add ***use TargetPathTrait*** on top of the class:

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    //...class methods
}
```

Now you can use ***getTargetPath()*** method, which uses the session and provider key to get required values:

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    //[...]

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('homepage'));
    }

    //[...]
}
```

Note, that the targetPath can in fact be empty. This happens if user goes to the login path directly for example. In that case you can redirect the user to homepage for example.

Answer (score 0):

I was also confronted with this issue.
I will assume you use ```Symfony4.4``` and used the ```make:auth``` to create the login interface.
In your ```SecurityController``` (the one where you have the login path), you use ```$request->headers->get('referer')``` to pass the URL you came from to the twig login page.

```
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, Request $request): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'back_to_your_page' => $request->headers->get('referer')
        ]);
    }
```

Then in your Twig page (login.html.twig) you use the `back_to_your_page` variable in your login form. The `_target_path` variable is essential here.

```
<form>
...
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ back_to_your_page }}"/>
...
</form>
```

Now the last part. In your LoginFormAuthenticator (make:auth), where the `onAuthenticationSuccess` function is, you use the `_target_path` variable.

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($request->get('_target_path'));
    }
```

Test and enjoy. I know it's a late response but maybe someone else will be helped in the future.